# Deny googlebot to index links generated for ajax

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I have links generated for a voting system... and i use like this:

```
<span onclick="$.post('/517e98dddbf67381c8a4d6b8ad51af7f/35227a57496b9008467abbda51787000/1/154/'...
```

In google webmaster tools > crawl errors > i have more than 3000 links whrong indexed becouse google try to get such links from onclick...

> /517e98dddbf67381c8a4d6b8ad51af7f/35227a57496b9008467abbda51787000/1/154/

The problem it's that i can't disallow from robots.txt becouse this is a dynamic generated link... It is there a solution for this ?

Comment: give those links a unique prefix, e.g. `/vote/517e9....`, then explicity deny `/vote*`?

Comment: thank you but i can`t rewrite the entire project...